# MVC Remote Validation Not calling function or working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, remote-validation, validationattribute

MVC Remote Validation not working, I'm new to MVC, any help is appreciated:

WebConfig:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

Controller:

```
   [AllowAnonymous]
    public JsonResult CheckAccount(string client_id)
    {
        var user = db.LGC_InboundData_c.Where(x => x.client_id == 
         client_id.Trim());
        return !user.Any() ?
           Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) :
           Json(string.Format("{0} is already exists."),
               JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Model Class:

```
[Remote("CheckAccount", "Home", ErrorMessage = "Account already exists!")]
        public string client_id { get; set; }
```

View:

```
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.client_id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-xs-10" })
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.client_id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.client_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have no idea why its not working. project is not calling the CheckAccount() function. I added the scripts in my view, but got this error message:

[image]

Comment: What is not working? Are you hitting the `CheckAccount()` method? Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: "not working" isn't an error message or problem description. Give us a specific, precise description of what is behaving incorrectly. Ideally supply any error messages, warnings or other unexpected output you get, either from the GUI, the browser console or the server. From your very vague description and just some code it's not really possible to give accurate advice to help you. You need to do a bit of debugging yourself in order to narrow down the problem. e.g. We don't know if it's the ajax itself which fails, or the DB query, or nothing "fails" but you just get the wrong results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so everyone knows: HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled was set to false.

Correct Syntax.

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

You only included a portion of your View, so my only recommendation can be to make sure that the following scripts are including in your View/Layout:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```